# Verbatim's Equivalent Word Meaning Letter for Letter

Tags: word-choice

Verbatim means word for word.  I also use it to mean letter for letter.  Is there a better choice meaning letter for letter?

Comment: Could you give us an example of how you're using the word?  Some synonyms are appropriate in one context but not another.

Comment: *Litteratim*. You'll also find *verbatim et litteratim*.

Comment: Thanks, Stoney!  Make it an answer so I can accept.  I found it in the dictionary with one 'T', literatim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Literatim*. You'll also find *[verbatim et literatim](http://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/oi/authority.20110803115457130)*. – StoneyB

However this usage is rare, you may need to explain it. In general use "verbatim" means both word for word *and* letter for letter.

If you want to keep things simple you can use "exactly" as it "He copied the text exactly".

Answer (score 0):

*Verbatim* is one of the English words that are hard to be given a synonym. LDOCE 5th version gives the meaning as follows:

> (verbatim, formal:) repeating the actual words that were spoken or written

There are some more synonyms offered by [linguee.de](https://www.linguee.de/deutsch-englisch/search?source=auto&query=wortw%C3%B6rtlich) (here I used a German word for finding out more about the possible synonyms of verbatim):

> literal or word-for-word

Here are the examples:

> Their stories were taped and transcribed **verbatim**.
>
> A trade war is not a war in the **literal** sense.
>
> The newspaper printed his speech more or less **word for word**.